# WPF FindAncestor binding finds source in Release, fails in Debug

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a binding error that makes no sense.  It always works in Release Mode.  It sometimes -- only sometimes -- fails to find the source via `FindAncestor` in Debug Mode

Its for Style for a WPF `Path` that I use only when that `Path` is inside a specific custom control named `LayerView`.  Below is the style.  Note the 3 bindings that look for the parent source object `LayerView` are the ones that sometimes fail

```
<Style x:Key="LayerViewGuidePathStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Path}">


    <Setter Property="Data">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CvtGuideOption}">
                <Binding Source="{svc:ViewSettings}, Path=GuideOption}" />
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ctrl:LayerView}}" Path="ScanWidth"      Converter="{ctrl:LogValueConverter}"/>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ctrl:LayerView}}" Path="ScanHeight"     Converter="{ctrl:LogValueConverter}"/>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ctrl:LayerView}}" Path="SceneTransform" Converter="{ctrl:LogValueConverter}"/>
            </MultiBinding>

        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When they fail in Debug mode, this is the warning

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
> reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
> AncestorType='MyControls.LayerView', AncestorLevel='1''.
> BindingExpression:Path=ScanHeight; DataItem=null; target element is
> 'Path' (Name='GuidePath'); target property is 'Data' (type 'Geometry')

Here is how I use this style inside my custom control `LayerView`

```
<ctrl:LayerView x:Name="MainLayerView" ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}">

    <ctrl:LayerView.Layers>
        <Path x:Name="GuidePath" Style="{StaticResource LayerViewGuidePathStyle}" />
    </ctrl:LayerView.Layers>

</ctrl:LayerView>
```

As you can probably tell, `LayerView` is an `ItemsControl`:  Specifically a `MultiSelector`.  My custom version merely adds non-dependency property named `Layers` which is a `Collection<object>`.  The idea is that the user will set these statically in XAML, as I did above, and I will display them over the standard items of the control.

```
public class LayerView : MultiSelector
{
    static LayerView()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(LayerView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(LayerView)));
    }

    private Collection<object>? _layers;
    public Collection<object> Layers => _layers ??= new Collection<object>();
}
```

Finally, here is the  `ControlTemplate` for `LayerView`.  In addition to the required `ItemsPresenter`, I add an `ItemsControl` to show the contents of `Layers` as basically non-hit-detectable "overlays"

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="LayerViewTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type gcl:LayerView}">

    <Canvas x:Name="PART_MainCanvas" Background="Transparent">

        <!-- We are an ItemsControl so present our items -->

        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PART_Items" />

        <!-- Now present our custom layers. -->

        <ItemsControl x:Name="PART_Layers" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Layers}"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"/>


    </Canvas>
</ControlTemplate
```

I have no moves here.  I can usually fix bindings that fail, but I would expect consistent failure or success.  Not a mix.  And especially not intermittent failures  It's almost as if it's a race condition.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this would fail?  Is my `Layers` property of the wrong type or is it missing some crucial attribute or something?

Answer (score 0):

Without reproducing this error, of course, it is difficult to say exactly what the cause is. But I have some guesses.

1. The elements of the Layers collection are initialized BEFORE being added to the collection, but the binding is resolved after the element is loaded;
2. Layers is a regular CLR collection and information about loading ItemsControl (LayerView ) is not passed to it. Therefore, the elements of this collection, as I think, are initialized completely at once, including bindings. And this can happen before these items are included in the ItemsControl panel.
3. As I think, these errors also occur in Release, it's just that not all errors are caught in this mode. It is guaranteed that only errors that are critical for the operation of the application are caught. For example, exceptions.

At a minimum, you need to replace the collection with a FreezableCollection and implement a read-only DependecyProperty.
True, in this case, you can only include DependencyObject in it.

```cs
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey LayersPropertyKey
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
            nameof(Layers),
            typeof(FreezableCollection<DependencyObject>),
            typeof(LayerView),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) => ((LayerView)d).protectedLayers = (FreezableCollection<DependencyObject>)e.NewValue));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LayersProperty
        = LayersPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    public FreezableCollection<DependencyObject> Layers
    {
        get => (FreezableCollection<DependencyObject>)GetValue(LayersProperty); 
    }

    // An optional auxiliary property for quickly obtaining a collection
    // in the internal logic of the LayerView and its derivatives.
    protected FreezableCollection<DependencyObject> protectedLayers {get; private set;}

    // Initializing a Collection in a Constructor.
    public LayerView() => SetValue(LayersPropertyKey, new FreezableCollection<DependencyObject>());
```

**Supplement**
Unfortunately, I could not immediately check your version - there was no "at hand" computer with the Studio.
Now I checked it.
I did not change the code of the LayerView element itself, I did not set the template in the style.
I got the Binding error only if the Element Template is not set.

```xml
<Window x:Class="Core2023.SO.Joe.BindingErrors.BindingErrorsWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2023.SO.Joe.BindingErrors"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="BindingErrorsWindow" Height="150" Width="400">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="LayerViewTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:LayerView}">

            <ItemsControl x:Name="PART_Layers" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Layers}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <local:LayerView>
            <local:LayerView.Layers>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:LayerView}}}"/>
            </local:LayerView.Layers>
        </local:LayerView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

[image]

In order to accurately diagnose the cause of your problem, I need more complete code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of answer I was hoping for.  In the time since I posted my question, I did already try the `ReadOnlyDependencyProperty` approach on my own without success, so at least I got that far.  But had not thought about making it `Freezeable` also.  (I had just tried making it an `IEnumerable`).  Perhaps that will do the trick.  And understanding the order and process of initialization is quite helpful.   I will try that and post back.  Thank you for this, regardless.  I realize it was a lot to parse

Comment: Sadly, I could not get that to work.  It basically worked exactly as before.   Sometimes it showed.  Sometimes it did not.   I tried monkeying around with the new `Layers` property as you suggested I write it though.  I  tried giving it `FrameworkPropertyMetaData instead of just `PropertyMetaData` and tried setting the flags like `AffectsRender` and `AffectsLayout` but that did not help.

Comment: However I did find an approach that seems to work all the time.  If replace the `Path` object with a `ContentControl`, and I set its `Content` property to be the `GuideOption` I referred to above and set its `ContentTemplate` to a custom `DataTemplate` that basically defines the  Path as I showed it above.... well that *does*  appear to work every time.  I admit I have no idea *why* it works but I've gone far into the weeds here...

Comment: @Joe , Read the supplement to my answer

Comment: I apologize for not following up on this.  I do appreciate your efforts.  Right now  I am in the middle of a final rush week to a software release and am working just about every waking hour.  My workaround will get my by for the release.  But I do want to understand this fully.  I will supplement my own post and continue the discussion as soon as I get a breather.